# @types/jest index.d.ts file returning error

Tags: typescript, npm, jestjs, stenciljs

I just npm installed @types/jest to my stenciljs starter app and now, when I go to start my project the newly installed node package is returning several errors. Here are the errors it's returning when I go to `npm start` my project:

```
[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:39:30
           A rest parameter must be of an array type.

     L39:  type ArgsType<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:218:112
           A tuple type element list cannot be empty.

    L217:   */
    L218:  ction spyOn<T extends {}, M extends keyof T>(object: T, method: M, accessType: 'get'): SpyInstance<T[M], []>;
    L219:  function spyOn<T extends {}, M extends keyof T>(object: T, method: M, accessType: 'set'): SpyInstance<void, [T[M]]>;

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:220:144
           Type 'ArgsType<T[M]>' does not satisfy the constraint 'any[]'. Type
           '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Property 'length' is missing
           in type '{}'.

    L219:  function spyOn<T extends {}, M extends keyof T>(object: T, method: M, accessType: 'set'): SpyInstance<void, [T[M]]>;
    L220:   T, method: M): T[M] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? SpyInstance<ReturnType<T[M]>, ArgsType<T[M]>> : never;
    L221:  /**

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:807:50
           Type 'ArgsType<T[P]>' does not satisfy the constraint 'any[]'. Type
           '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

    L806:  type Mocked<T> = {
    L807:      [P in keyof T]: T[P] & MockInstance<T[P], ArgsType<T[P]>>;
    L808:  } & T;
```

This is my package.json:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@stencil/core": "~0.15.2",
    "@stencil/router": "~0.3.1",
    "imask": "^4.1.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.14",
    "@types/puppeteer": "1.12.1",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-cli": "23.6.0",
    "puppeteer": "1.8.0",
    "workbox-build": "3.4.1"
  }
...
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "jsxFactory": "h"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I have tried replicating the error with a fresh stencil starter app and it's not the app. Also, tried deleting my `package-lock.json` and reinstalling the packages to get rid of any potential conflicts.

Comment: Try removing @types/jest-cli. You probably have some global conflict between the two.

Comment: @unional I tried it still the same error appears

Comment: Not sure what it is then. I'm using @types/jest@24 and it is working fine for me.
Maybe sharing your `tsconfig.json` would help.

Comment: @unional Yeah, it's pretty strange. I've updated the post with my tsconfig.json. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Although unrelated, you don't need `allowSynth...` use `esModuleInterop` instead.

Comment: Can you share the full dependencies and devDependencies from your package.json? Curious about your TypeScript version and perhaps whether you have two libraries whose types are conflicting with each other.

Comment: @ecraig12345 I updated the post

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding `"skipLibCheck": true` to `tsconfig.json` to skip type checking of all declaration (.d.ts) files.

EDIT: This is more of a "sledgehammer" workaround than an actual fix. As referenced in the other answer, this issue probably happens because the Jest typings were made for a newer TypeScript version than the one being used in the project. So the proper fix would be upgrading the project to a newer TS version.

Comment: Hey @hawaiiansurfer, where you able to find a solution by any chance without enabling skipLibCheck?

Answer (score 7):

I hope this is not too late and might be helpful to someone.

Instead of skipping all library checks, you can override the libraries you want. In our case that would be:`@types/jest`

As an alternative to setting
`"skipLibCheck": true` to `tsconfig.json`

you can create a new folder and file from your root:
`overrides/jest/index.d.ts`
and add

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "overrides",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
}
```

This would essentially override all the types check under the `overrides` folder and fallback to `./node_modules/@types` except jest thanks to `overrides/jest/index.d.ts` file which can be empty.

I found this answer on
https://medium.com/@elenasufieva/handling-type-declarations-clash-in-typescript-b05b10723f47

Answer (score 1):

Updating typescript version to `3.3.4000` helped me.