# Suppress an ERRNO 2 error in typescript compilation

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have an error in my compilation that is the following:

```
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(256,23): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(258,9): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(258,16): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(278,26): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(278,50): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(279,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(279,56): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(279,62): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(279,69): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(280,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(280,57): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(280,60): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(282,63): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(282,115): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(284,60): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(284,104): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(284,112): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(404,32): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(404,33): error TS1003: Identifier expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(912,11): error TS1005: '>' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(912,24): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(912,39): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(912,40): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(912,42): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(913,7): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(914,22): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(914,30): error TS1005: ':' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(914,74): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(914,81): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(929,30): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(931,13): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(931,20): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(933,13): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(934,5): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(934,7): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(935,10): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(1128,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! SocleTechniqueClient@0.0.0 tsc-compile-client: `node ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -p projects/framework/tsconfig.client.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the SocleTechniqueClient@0.0.0 tsc-compile-client script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I would like for my compilation to run without this error, however, I cannot fix the error since it's due to an uncompatibility of my typescript version (2.7.1) and the typing file's syntax of jest.

Hence, I wish to suppress the errors altogether. Some research lead me to the use of the `--silent` option, it does in fact suppress the `npm ERR! errno 2` but I still get all the syntax error lines of jest's typing.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639274/types-jest-index-d-ts-file-returning-error) suggests adding a `"skipLibCheck": true` to the `tsconfig` file, but it did not work for me.

I am looking for a way to suppress even those messages.

BTW: 
My `tsconfig` looks something like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../../build/",
    "outFile": "../../build/framework-client.js",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts"
    ],
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "files": [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude your `node_modules` folder. Update you tsconfig file into

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../../build/",
    "outFile": "../../build/framework-client.js",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts"
    ],
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "files": [...]
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually that would land me other errors `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'fail'.` (`expect`, `it`, etc). So while I'd like to avoid the compilation erros of the jest typings, I'd like to compile files that contain these keywords !

Comment: Maybe a more precise question is how to deal with typings for tests in compilation of old versions of typescript (2.7.1 and older) ?